# Rudin Chapter 1, Exercise 1: (Q6): Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^r b^s$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**: Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^r b^s$, if $r$ and $s$ are rational numbers.

This seems pretty obvious, but I am not sure as to which theorems or Field axioms should I use in order to prove this.

Comment: How about writing $r=p/q$ and $s=p'/q'$ where $r,s>0$?

Comment: Your allowed to use $b^nb^m=b ^{n+m} $ for integers because $b^n$ is just notation for $b*b*b.... $. For rationals you must prove $\sqrt [nq]{b}^{mq+np}=\sqrt[n]{b}^m\sqrt [q]{b}^p $

Comment: @fleablood I think you're missing a $ ;)

Comment: Frigging phone app. I can not proof anything as latex is not rendered in comments.  So I don't have the slightest frigging idea what I did or did not type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have 
\begin{align}
r = \frac{m}{n} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ s = \frac{p}{q}
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
r+s = \frac{mq+pn}{nq}.
\end{align}
Next, observe
\begin{align}
b^{mq+pn}= b^{mq}b^{pn} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (b^{mq+pn})^{1/nq}= (b^{mq}b^{pn})^{1/nq}= (b^{mq})^{1/nq}(b^{pn})^{1/nq}.
\end{align}
Since we have shown (at least the problem should have asked you to show that) if $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, then 
\begin{align}
(\alpha^{a})^{1/b} = (\alpha^{c})^{1/d}. 
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
(b^{mq})^{1/nq}(b^{pn})^{1/nq}= (b^m)^{1/n}(b^p)^{1/q}.
\end{align}
In conclusion, we have
\begin{align}
b^{r+s}=(b^{mq+pn})^{1/nq} = (b^m)^{1/n}(b^p)^{1/q}= b^rb^s. 
\end{align}